# Add a folder to a document library and break permission inheritence

Tags: 2013, development, document-library, permissions

I have a web part that is being used to manually add folders to document libraries (Part of the requirements is that only administrators can add folders, contributors must only be able to add documents)

The code to add a new folder is as follows

```
    selectedFolderID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlPnlfFuncArea.SelectedItem.Value);
    SPListItem selFolderItem = docLibrary.GetItemById(selectedFolderID);
    SPFolder folder = selFolderItem.Folder;
    folder.SubFolders.Add(txtPnlfFolder.Text);
```

How can I retrieve the SPListItem of the newly added folder to call the `BreakRoleInheritance(bool keepPermission)` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get an instance of the newly added folder then you can get the `SPListItem` object corresponding to the folder.

```
// Get instance of the newly added folder
SPFolder newSubFolder = folder.SubFolders.Add(txtPnlfFolder.Text);

// BreakRoleInheritance of the folder
newSubFolder.Item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
```